# java stack reading from an array throws ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException

Tags: java, stack, indexoutofboundsexception

I need to fill a stack from an array, then print out the elements in order and then again reversing the order. What I'm having problems with is I'm getting an ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException and cant figure out where it is coming from. I have tried running through the debug and it appears as I'm popping off elements it never reaches the last element. Below is my code:

```
public class arrayStack {

    private int top;
    private String[] storage;

    public arrayStack(int capacity)
    {
        storage = new String[capacity];
        top = -1;
    }

    public boolean isEmpty() {
        return (top == 0);
    }

    String peek() {
        return storage[top];    
    }

    String pop() {
        top--;
        return storage[top];
    }

    public void push(String str) {
        top++;
        storage[top] = str;
    }

}
```

StackMain.java:

```
public class StackMain {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //int j = 5;
        String[] list = new String[5];

        list[0] = "Beware";
        list[1] = "The";
        list[2] = "Ides";
        list[3] = "Of";
        list[4] = "March";

        arrayStack stack = new arrayStack(5);

        for(int i = 0; i < list.length; i++)
        {
            stack.push(list[i]);
        }

        for(int j = 0; j < list.length; j++)
            System.out.println(stack.pop());

    }

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In `pop()`, you need to return the item that was popped, which is the item at the index of the old value of `top`. Cleanest way is to change the function to

```
String pop() {
    return storage[top--];
}
```

**Edit**
You also need to change `isEmpty()` to `return (top == -1)`. You could also change the implementation to use `size` (the number of elements) instead of `top` (the index of the highest element) like others mentioned.

Comment: Thank you very much, that was a simple answer that i have been fighting for all afternoon.

Answer (score 1):

In your constructor for `arrayStack`, you should set `top` to 0, rather than to -1. In your `isEmpty` method, you even check that `top == 0`, so clearly `top == 0` means empty, rather than `top == -1`. This is why you always miss the last element when popping off values from the stack; putting the first element increments `top` to 0.

Oh, and I missed what tom said, below: decrementing `top` before you find the value at the top will return the wrong element. His code below is preferable, but this might be more easy to understand for a beginner:

```
public String pop() {
    String topValue = storage[top];
    top--;
    return topValue;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you `push(String)` just one element, with top initialized to -1, what will the value of top be after the push?

Now look at your `pop()` function, it decrements top *before* trying to get the element requested, so what array index is it going to try to access if you've pushed just one element?

Answer (score 1):

Since you start `top` at -1, once you have added your 5 elements from the String array `top` will be 4, which is incorrect since you have 5 elements.

Then when you try to pop the stack 5 times, `top` goes back to -1 and `storage[-1]` doesn't exist so you get an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`

Start `top` at 0.

Alternatively if you decrement `top` after you retrieve the element from you stack, you won't get an error; but it would be better to start `top` at 0 because `top` is really representing the number of elements in your stack.

Answer (score 1):

Please tag the question as homework. And coming to the problem, the problem is in the pop() function. You are decrementing the value of top first and then returning the element. But when you check the push() function, you are incrementing first and then adding the element. So, if you move the `top--` to after getting the element from the stack your problem will be solved.

Answer (score 1):

Your pop method is incorrect. In your code here, top starts at negative 1.

When you push an element, top becomes 0.
When you pop an element, the top becomes -1 before you access the element.

Also, your empty method is incorrect. In the initial state of the stack, top = -1, and isEmpty checks if it returns 0. Initially the stack should be empty.

Answer (score 1):

your pop() function must be changed. You must store storage[pop]  in a temporary variable and then reduce top by 1 and then return the temporary variable

Answer (score 1):

It would be great if you can include java 1.5 generics facility to implement stack.Then your stack will be more flexible.It can hold any type of objects(in you case only Strings)
And one more advice is in the pop method you should tell garbage collector to discard to poped object as follows. (In the case if you are using generics) Following is a more flexible stack implementation which mentioned in effective java edition 2.

```
// Initial attempt to generify Stack = won’t compile!
public class Stack<E> {
private E[] elements;
private int size = 0;
private static final int DEFAULT_INITIAL_CAPACITY = 16;
public Stack() {
elements = (E[])new E[DEFAULT_INITIAL_CAPACITY];
}
public void push(E e) {
ensureCapacity();
elements[size++] = e;
}
public E pop() {
if (size==0)
throw new EmptyStackException();
E result = elements[--size];
elements[size] = null; // Eliminate obsolete reference
return result;
}
```